# IndexOutOfBoundException in EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm using custom editText for showing number value, It working in most of the time but some time it throw IndexOutOfBoundsException.
CustomEditText,

class FixedCursorEditText : EditText {

```
constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs)

constructor(context: Context) : super(context)

constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyle: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyle)

override fun onSelectionChanged(selStart: Int, selEnd: Int) {
    this.text?.length?.let { this.setSelection(it) }
}
```

}

XML file,

```
<sample.example.views.FixedCursorEditText
    android:id="@+id/enterAmountEditText"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryText"
    android:digits="0123456789"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:text="@={ viewModel.amount }"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
    android:textSize="32sp"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryText"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    >
    <requestFocus />
<sample.example.views.FixedCursorEditText>
```

In fragment,

```
    var currentValue = viewModel.parse(viewModel.amount.value) ?: 0
    currentValue += amount
    viewModel.amount.value = currentValue.toString()
    enterAmountEditText.text?.length?.let { enterAmountEditText.setSelection(it) }
```

Can you help me for solving this issue.

Error log,

IndexOutOfBoundsException: offset(3) should be less than line limit(0)
at sample.example.views.FixedCursorEditText.onSelectionChanged(FixedCursorEditText.kt:15)
at sample.example.databinding.FragmentAmountBindingImpl.executeBindings(FragmentAmountBindingImpl.java:291)

Comment: could you post error log?

Comment: Here is error log, IndexOutOfBoundsException: offset(3) should be less than line limit(0) at sample.example.views.FixedCursorEditText.onSelectionChanged(FixedCursorEditText.kt:15) at sample.example.databinding.FragmentAmountBindingImpl.executeBindings(FragmentAmountBindingImpl.java:291)

Comment: okay, checking your code now... seems index of setSelection was wrong. anyway, let me check.

Comment: try this:  this.text?.length?.let { this.setSelection(it - 1) }

Comment: Thank you @UsmanRana, although it's not working

Comment: I've tested your code in my env. It's working perfectly. I suppose your error occurred during binding ViewModel and View.

Comment: please confirm that setSelection is not calling for 0 length as it would also cause crash.

Comment: Thank you all of you, I finally solve the issue by changing 
    enterAmountEditText.text?.length?.let { enterAmountEditText.setSelection(it - 1 ) }